# Laravel Eloquent query build select min value

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am having the following query (trimmed) to list the rooms to user for booking:

```
$buildquery=Room::

        with(['hotel' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        }])

        ->with('image')->with('amenities');

        if ($request->filled('location_id')) {
            $buildquery->Where('city', $request->location_id);
        }

        $buildquery->Where('astatus', 1)->Where('status', 0);

        $rooms = $buildquery->simplePaginate(20);
```

Actual query (not trimmed):

```
select `rooms`.*, 
(select count(*) from `amenities` inner join `amenities_room` on `amenities`.`id` = `amenities_room`.`amenities_id` where `rooms`.`id` = `amenities_room`.`room_id` and `amenities_id` in (?)) as `amenities_count` 
from 
`rooms` 
where `city` = ? and `price` between ? and ? and `astatus` = ? and `status` = ? having 
`amenities_count` = ? 
limit 21 offset 100
```

It lists all the rooms available in hotel. I need to select only one room for one hotel with least price.

Answer (score 0):

You can `use order by`

```
$buildquery->orderBy('COL_NAME', 'DESC')->get();
```

if you need only one you can use `take(1)`

Comment: Your query gives total only one result. Note: im having many hotel (each hotel has many rooms)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly. you want the lowest priced rooms for each hotel that you have. Than it's better to make relations from hotel model and make a query like `Hotel::with('room' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('price', 'asc')->first();
}])
    ->get();`

Comment: Hmm also thinking the same. But all relations already built to rooms like (amenities, room types, images) and location fields are available in room only

Answer (score 0):

```
Hotel::with('room' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('price', 'asc')->first();
},
'room.images',
'room.roomTypes',
'room.amenities'])
->get();
```

You can do something like this to get structure like:

```
{
    'Hotel': {
        'Room': {
            'Images': {
                //
            },
            'roomTypes': {
                //
            },
            'amenities': {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: It looks promising, let me try that

Comment: Miss open square bracket, sorry.
    Hotel::with(['room' => function($query) {

Comment: The above query partially works, i am having this amenities filter : if amenities selected i am adding this query,
if($request->filled('amenities')){
            $amenities = $request->amenities;
            $count = count($amenities);
             
            $buildquery->withCount(['amenities' => function($query) use ($amenities){
                            $query->whereIn('amenities_id', $amenities);
                        }])
                        ->having('amenities_count', $count);
        }
how to add this to above query?

Comment: if u have time look this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919059/laravel-eloquent-one-to-many-relationship-dynamically-adding-query-to-the-relat)